# Websphere OutOfMemory Vaadin6

Tags: java, out-of-memory, vaadin, websphere-7, heap-dump

I've got OutOfMemory in IBM WAS7(41) vaadin6 (6.8.17) application.

Win2008R2 12CPU 32Gb.
WAS7 - 24Gb (if I not mistaken) 
And I really need help.

Here is Heap dump screenshot:[image]

Here is was7 JVM settings:[image]

Comment: This is a very broad question and it is very difficult to pinpoint memory leaks. However -from the dump my first shot would be something is placing too much information into the http session and not cleaning up (do I see well a DB connection referred from the session map???) There are simply too much entries in the hash map so I'd guess something is cached / store what should not

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain "do I see well a DB connection referred from the session map???".

Comment: I have main app class `public class WorkplaceApplication extends Application ` and field `private DB db = new DB()` which initialize mssql connection, which stay connected about all time of `WorkplaceApplication ` application..

Comment: Here is an entry of java core: `"Dump Event "systhrow" (00040000) Detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" "Unable to allocate memory for  JNIEnv" received".` Can anybody suggest some "top 5" rules of clean code to prevent this memory leak. (eg. always close InputStream,...) Thanks.

Comment: The "Unable to allocate memory" is just "the last drop". Seeing the screenshot I'd suggest you to focus in collections (see number of Hashmap$Entry classes). I'd say there are too many in-memory sessions (it is possible to set [a ilmit WAS 7](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4580.pdf))  but I'd guess that something is gathered in the session, Please log your session hashmap attributes before crash.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Could you kindly explain how to obtain "session hashmap attributes"? 
You mean get attributes of `HttpSession`?

Comment: Indeed I meant the attributes of the HttpSession and  the ServletContext. The intent is that you make sure that there's no hashmap which gathers some data and never release them..